# Who's going to AES in October?

Tags: aes, conventions, gear, community

Wanted to started a group to see who will be at AES in NYC this October.

I'll be there from Oct 19 - Oct 24.

I'm presenting "Techniques in Field Recording" in the Game Audio track on the morning of the 21st.

I'd love to get together with some of you - both those I've met and those I haven't!

Hope to see some of you there!

Comment: Awe, wish I could attend...

Comment: @Colin Wish I could be there Colin! Unfortunately, I'm London based :(. Good Luck with the presentation though!

Answer (score 1):

I'll see you there, Colin. ;)

**EDIT:** holy crap! between sessions, appointments and the yet to be scheduled drink-ups...i'm wondering if i'm actually going to sleep while i'm there.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be there as well. Shaun, sleep is for the dead.

Answer (score 0):

If all goes well and my gig in the UK finishes on schedule I should be able to swing by on the way back and attend your presentation. Would love to meet up! Great idea.

Answer (score 0):

I will be there, we should meet up.